# Grails 3.1.8 with spring security core using multiple datasources

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

I'm facing problem with grails spring-security-core plugin/spring-ldap plugin. Here is my first post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701893/error-while-deploying-grails-app-on-tomcat-8),  and full [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/bT1ztRbs). Here is the problem:

I have an app with multpile datasources and spring-security-core plugin added by

```
`build.gradle ` `compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"`
```

running this app in build in tomcat server, it works great, but when I try to deploy war file in my own tomcat, it fails with error (in the link), i have been trying to find what cause it, first solution is turning off second level cache, second solution is removing spring-security-core plugin from project. I don't know if it is a bug or maybe I'm missing some configuration, maybe default configuration is not enough?. Project was working in previous grails version 3.0.x. If you want to reproduce error simply create new grails project - with web profile, add more then one datasource (oracle,mssql) and try to deploy it on tomcat.

I thought it may be some problem with plugin dependencies because it also uses ehcache, and i have dependency to `hibernate-ehcache`, but excluding `ehcache-core` didnt help.  Here is repo with sample project which fails [link](https://bitbucket.org/trokitasnt/grailstest)

Comment: Good work on putting it all together. If you have it in a sample app put that up on git hub and reference it here on this question.  That will then make it easier for others to easily produce issue locally without having to recreate app etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you have noticed it, but your stacktrace states clearly that you have create a duplicate CacheManager. You may want to check your ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the
ame VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessa
y
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
        at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.jav
:91)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
        ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names
for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessa
y
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
```

**UPDATE**: you may want to consider the configuration of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524547/grails-2-5-another-unnamed-cachemanager-already-exists-in-the-same-vm-when-us). Basically they are using a shared singleton bean, so it would avoid the re-creation of the cache:

**DataSource.Groovy:**

```
cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'
```

and

**Config.groovy:**

```
    cacheManager {
        shared = true
    }
```

I'm not sure if it is indeed your case or not (we don't see your configuration), but it's a start.

Comment: I didny create any configuration file fo CacheManager, also it was not necesary in previous version of grails. I dont have file `DataSource.Groovy` and `Config.groovy` since i'm using 3.1.8 version. Anyway i have default factory_class and default shared settings and it was working previously. I have read my stackstrace, but i have written that problem disapear when spring-security plugin is not added, so there must be some conflict in plugin configuration.

Comment: This solution works, thats right, but right now i have to wait with accepting it. Since its describes problem from grails 2.5 version. And i'm using default settings which shoudl be correct. Thanks anyway for temporary solution!

Comment: Hi, no problem :) . I believe that the version of Grails doesn't matter much here. From the stack trace & your description, it is likely that Spring-security plugin is doing something which create the eh-cache duplicate CacheManager object. It is difficult to tell unless you turn on the log on Spring-security. What this solution does is to force EhCache always use one CacheManager only, therefore avoid the problem.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the info. It has been a while since last time I use Grails. In case you find out what's wrong with the Spring Security, please let me know too